# Sobel Filter in C without structs and with 1D arrays,

Tags: c, filter, sobel

I have the following sobel filter code that runs correctly.
I want to transform it in code with 1D arrays and without structs. My attempt runs but the output image is not the right one...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Image.h"  
    
RGBQUAD image[2048][2048];          // Image as input

int main(int  argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *filename = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *wp;
  int width, height;
  int i, j, x, y, T;
  BitmapFileHeader bmfh;
  BitmapInfoHeader bmih;    
  unsigned char ee_image[2048][2048];

  // Reading inputs: bayer image and threshold
  if (argc == 3){
    filename = argv[1];
    T = atoi(argv[2]);
  } else{ 
    printf("Give a bmp image and a threshold as input\n");
    exit(0); 
  }
      
  // Opening the file: using "rb" mode to read this *binary* file
  printf("Opening filename: %s\n", filename);
  fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

  // Reading the file header and any following bitmap information...
  fread(&bmfh, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), 1, fp);
  fread(&bmih, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), 1, fp);

  printf("Header Info\n");
  printf("--------------------\n");
  printf("Size:%i\n", bmfh.bfSize);
  printf("Offset:%i\n", bmfh.bfOffBits);
  printf("--------------------\n");
  printf("Size:%i\n", bmih.biSize);
  printf("biWidth:%i\n", bmih.biWidth);
  printf("biHeight:%i\n", bmih.biHeight);
  printf("biPlanes:%i\n", bmih.biPlanes);
  printf("biBitCount:%i\n", bmih.biBitCount);
  printf("biCompression:%i\n", bmih.biCompression);
  printf("biSizeImage:%i\n", bmih.biSizeImage);
  printf("biXPelsPerMeter:%i\n", bmih.biXPelsPerMeter);
  printf("biYPelsPerMeter:%i\n", bmih.biYPelsPerMeter);
  printf("biClrUsed:%i\n", bmih.biClrUsed);
  printf("biClrImportant:%i\n", bmih.biClrImportant);
  printf("--------------------\n");
  
  // Reading the pixels of input image
  width  = bmih.biWidth; if (width%4 != 0) width += (4-width%4);
  height = bmih.biHeight;
  for (y=0; y<height; y++) 
    for (x=0; x<width; x++){
      image[x][y].rgbBlue = fgetc(fp);  
      image[x][y].rgbGreen = fgetc(fp);
      image[x][y].rgbRed = fgetc(fp);
  }

  fclose(fp);

 
 
  // Converting from RGB to Grayscale
  int gray_image[width][height];
  memset(gray_image, 0, width*height*sizeof(int));
  
  for (y=0; y<height; y++) 
    for (x=0; x<width; x++){
      gray_image[x][y] = 0.2989*image[x][y].rgbRed + 0.5870*image[x][y].rgbGreen + 0.1140*image[x][y].rgbBlue;
  }
 


  // mask for x direction
  double S1[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, 
                     {-2, 0, 2}, 
                     {-1, 0, 1}}; 
  // mask for y direction
  double S2[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, 
                     {0, 0, 0}, 
                     {1, 2, 1}};  

 
  // Scanning the image
  for (x=1; x<width-1; x++)
    for (y=1; y<height-1; y++){

      double Gx = S1[0][0]*gray_image[x-1][y-1] + S1[0][1]*gray_image[x-1][y] + S1[0][2]*gray_image[x-1][y+1] + 
                  S1[1][0]*gray_image[x][y-1]   + S1[1][1]*gray_image[x][y]   + S1[1][2]*gray_image[x][y+1]   +
                  S1[2][0]*gray_image[x+1][y-1] + S1[2][1]*gray_image[x+1][y] + S1[2][2]*gray_image[x+1][y+1];

      double Gy = S2[0][0]*gray_image[x-1][y-1] + S2[0][1]*gray_image[x-1][y] + S2[0][2]*gray_image[x-1][y+1] + 
                  S2[1][0]*gray_image[x][y-1]   + S2[1][1]*gray_image[x][y]   + S2[1][2]*gray_image[x][y+1]   + 
                  S2[2][0]*gray_image[x+1][y-1] + S2[2][1]*gray_image[x+1][y] + S2[2][2]*gray_image[x+1][y+1];
      
      double e = sqrt(Gx*Gx + Gy*Gy);

      // Thresholding
      if (e <= T) ee_image[x][y] = 0;
      if (e > T)  ee_image[x][y] = 255;
      
  } // End of image scanning 
 


  // Calculating the border pixels with replication
  for (y=1; y<height-1; y++){
    ee_image[0][y] = ee_image[1][y];
    ee_image[width-1][y] = ee_image[width-2][y];
  }
  for (x=0; x<width; x++){
    ee_image[x][0] = ee_image[x][1];
    ee_image[x][height-1] = ee_image[x][height-2];
  }
 

  printf("The edges of the image have been detected with Sobel and a Threshold: %d\n", T); 
   
  // Constructing output image name
  char dst_name[80];
  // Converting input threshold to string
  char str_T[3];
  sprintf(str_T, "%d", T);

  strcpy(dst_name, "Sobel_");
  strcat(dst_name, str_T);
  strcat(dst_name, ".bmp");

  // Writing new image
  wp = fopen(dst_name, "wb");
  fwrite(&bmfh, 1, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), wp);
  fwrite(&bmih, 1, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), wp);

  for (y=0; y<height; y++) 
    for (x=0; x<width; x++){
      fputc(ee_image[x][y], wp);
      fputc(ee_image[x][y], wp);
      fputc(ee_image[x][y], wp);                
  }

  fclose(wp);

}
```

My Code attempt is...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Image.h"

image[2048*2048];           // Image as input

int main(int  argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *filename = 0;
  FILE *fp;
  FILE *wp;
  int width, height;
  int i, j, x, y, T;
  BitmapFileHeader bmfh;
  BitmapInfoHeader bmih;
  unsigned char ee_image[2048*2048];

  // Reading inputs: bayer image and threshold
  if (argc == 3){
    filename = argv[1];
    T = atoi(argv[2]);
  } else{
    printf("Give a bmp image and a threshold as input\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  // Opening the file: using "rb" mode to read this *binary* file
  printf("Opening filename: %s\n", filename);
  fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

  // Reading the file header and any following bitmap information...
  fread(&bmfh, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), 1, fp);
  fread(&bmih, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), 1, fp);

  printf("Header Info\n");
  printf("--------------------\n");
  printf("Size:%i\n", bmfh.bfSize);
  printf("Offset:%i\n", bmfh.bfOffBits);
  printf("--------------------\n");
  printf("Size:%i\n", bmih.biSize);
  printf("biWidth:%i\n", bmih.biWidth);
  printf("biHeight:%i\n", bmih.biHeight);
  printf("biPlanes:%i\n", bmih.biPlanes);
  printf("biBitCount:%i\n", bmih.biBitCount);
  printf("biCompression:%i\n", bmih.biCompression);
  printf("biSizeImage:%i\n", bmih.biSizeImage);
  printf("biXPelsPerMeter:%i\n", bmih.biXPelsPerMeter);
  printf("biYPelsPerMeter:%i\n", bmih.biYPelsPerMeter);
  printf("biClrUsed:%i\n", bmih.biClrUsed);
  printf("biClrImportant:%i\n", bmih.biClrImportant);
  printf("--------------------\n");

  // Reading the pixels of input image
width  = bmih.biWidth; if (width%4 != 0) width += (4-width%4);
height = bmih.biHeight;
 
 for (y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (x=0; x<width; x++){
      image[x + y * width] = fgetc(fp);
      image[x + y * width] = fgetc(fp);
      image[x + y * width] = fgetc(fp);



  }

  fclose(fp);

  // Converting from RGB to Grayscale
  int gray_image[width*height];
  memset(gray_image, 0, width*height*sizeof(int));

  for (y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (x=0; x<width; x++){
      gray_image[x + y * width] = 0.2989*image[x + y * width] + 0.5870*image[x + y * width] + 0.1140*image[x + y * width];
  }

  // Sobel kernels
  // mask for x direction
  double S1[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1},
                     {-2, 0, 2},
                     {-1, 0, 1}};
  // mask for y direction
  double S2[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1},
                     {0, 0, 0},
                     {1, 2, 1}};

  // Scanning the image
  for (x=1; x<width-1; x++)
    for (y=1; y<height-1; y++){

      double Gx = S1[0][0]*gray_image[(x-1)*(y-1)] + S1[0][1]*gray_image[(x-1)*(y)] + S1[0][2]*gray_image[(x-1)*(y+1)] +
                  S1[1][0]*gray_image[x*(y-1)]   + S1[1][1]*gray_image[x + y * width]   + S1[1][2]*gray_image[x*(y+1)]   +
                  S1[2][0]*gray_image[(x+1)*(y-1)] + S1[2][1]*gray_image[(x+1)*y] + S1[2][2]*gray_image[(x+1)*(y+1)];

      double Gy = S2[0][0]*gray_image[(x-1)*(y-1)] + S2[0][1]*gray_image[(x-1)*(y)] + S2[0][2]*gray_image[(x-1)*(y+1)] +
                  S2[1][0]*gray_image[x*(y-1)]   + S2[1][1]*gray_image[x + y * width]   + S2[1][2]*gray_image[x*(y+1)]   +
                  S2[2][0]*gray_image[(x+1)*(y-1)] + S2[2][1]*gray_image[(x+1)*y] + S2[2][2]*gray_image[(x+1)*(y+1)];

      double e = sqrt(Gx*Gx + Gy*Gy);

      // Thresholding
      if (e <= T) ee_image[x + y * width] = 0;
      if (e > T)  ee_image[x + y * width] = 255;

  } // End of image scanning

  // Calculating the border pixels with replication
  for (y=1; y<height-1; y++){
    ee_image[0*y] = ee_image[1*y];
    ee_image[(width-1)*y] = ee_image[(width-2)*y];
  }
  for (x=0; x<width; x++){
    ee_image[x*0] = ee_image[x*1];
    ee_image[x*(height-1)] = ee_image[x*(height-2)];
  }

  printf("The edges of the image have been detected with Sobel and a Threshold: %d\n", T);

  // Constructing output image name
  char dst_name[80];
  // Converting input threshold to string
  char str_T[3];
  sprintf(str_T, "%d", T);

  strcpy(dst_name, "Sobel_");
  strcat(dst_name, str_T);
  strcat(dst_name, ".bmp");

  // Writing new image
  wp = fopen(dst_name, "wb");
  fwrite(&bmfh, 1, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), wp);
  fwrite(&bmih, 1, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), wp);
  for (y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (x=0; x<width; x++){
      fputc(ee_image[x + y * width], wp);
      fputc(ee_image[x + y * width], wp);
      fputc(ee_image[x + y * width], wp);}

  fclose(wp);

}
```

I have understand that sonething is wrong when i reaf the original image...
Any help would be precious.
Regards

"Image.h"

```
typedef struct tagBitmapFileHeader{
    unsigned short bfType;
    unsigned int bfSize;
    unsigned short bfReserved1;
    unsigned short bfReserved2;
    unsigned int bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((packed)) BitmapFileHeader;

typedef struct tagBitmapInfoHeader{
    unsigned int biSize;
    int biWidth;
    int biHeight;
    unsigned short biPlanes;
    unsigned short biBitCount;
    unsigned int biCompression;
    unsigned int biSizeImage;
    int biXPelsPerMeter;
    int biYPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int biClrUsed;
    unsigned int biClrImportant;
} __attribute__((packed)) BitmapInfoHeader; 

typedef struct{                      /**** Colormap entry structure ****/
    unsigned char  rgbBlue;          /* Blue value */
    unsigned char  rgbGreen;         /* Green value */
    unsigned char  rgbRed;           /* Red value */
    unsigned char  rgbReserved;      /* Reserved */
} RGBQUAD;

typedef struct{                      /**** Colormap entry structure ****/
    unsigned char  yccY;             /* Y value */
    unsigned char  yccCb;            /* Cb value */
    unsigned char  yccCr;            /* Cr value */
    unsigned char  yccReserved;      /* Reserved */
} YCCQUAD;
```

Comment: The original code handles RGB. Your code doesn't; for instance, you read each of the RGB values into the same location.

Comment: Jamming everything under the sun into `main()` is not a sustainable development practice. Split this up into functions. Not only does that help us understand the structure of your code a lot better, it makes it *way* easier to test.

Comment: What problem do you try to solve? What is the motivation to not use structs? Is the sole purpose to make things a bit harder or is there some actual problem behind that?

Comment: The motivation is for practice and then transform it in kernels for hardware acceleration.